# Process Builder is triggering for wrong usecase too

Tags: formula, process-builder, process

I have a requirement to assign leads created from a particular lead source from few states.

I have created the following process.
[image]

And sometimes state comes in lower case alphabet too. So while verifying I am verifying as the upper case for convenience.

Scenario 1:(Need to work)

Lead source = exp
Record type =leads
State/Province = in the list

Scenario 2:(Not to fire)

Lead source = exp
Record type =leads
State/Province = not in the list (Or Blank Field)

But scenario 2 is also firing

Please let me know where I missed it.

Comment: Could you be more specific about when the process is firing that is not desired?

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in my process is the result of the formula.

If anyone creates lead without state information process is firing because I'm returning blank state. Now I updated my process formula like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use process builder, use Lead Assignment Rule. That's the first advice. That should ease a little bit (also, the validation rules are triggered before the workflows, so there could be an impact somewhere somehow).

Comment: I tried to use in assignment rule like this.                                                            
AND(  ISPICKVAL( LeadSource , '') ,OR(UPPER( State ) =  'PA' ,UPPER(State) = 'MD',UPPER(State) = 'DE',UPPER(State) = 'DC' ,UPPER(State) = 'VA' ,UPPER(State) = 'WV',UPPER(State)= 'NC' ,UPPER(State) = 'SC' ,UPPER(State) = 'GA' ,UPPER(State) = 'FL'))

Comment: But it's not working.Please let me know

Comment: And so they need to check assignment rule to fire for this process. But in my case leads pushed from the external source.So they didn't check the assignment rule checkbox